# How to know firefox extension proxy

Tags: firefox, vpn, proxy

I'm using "Hoxx VPN" by Firefox extension. It's only work on Firefox but I want to use it on my telegram. when i turn it on there's no proxy info in Internet Options. How i can use of Hoxx proxy settings in telegram? I have win10;

Comment: Welcome to [su]! The solution will vary depending on the plugin. Firefox is one of the few programs which overrides the system proxy (as found in "Internet Options"). You may see the right value in the Firefox settings.